# Unable to set permissions for new files added to the directory

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to add permissions for my nginx html folder using the following:

```
sudo chown -R my-user:www-data /webdirectory
sudo chmod -R 0755 /webdirectory
```

It works for existing files in the directory, however any added files I need to execute those lines again.

Any solutions?

Comment: ok what is your `umask` mode creation? `755` is for a folder for a regular file is `666` if your `umask` is `0022` every new file created will have permissions `644` not `755` is this your issue? Or I misunderstood?:)

Comment: and that is why we have 'groups' ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `umask`. `umask` is a shell builin that will decide what will the default permission of a newly created file. The value of `umask` can vary from user to user.

To check the `umask` value of the current user, run `umask` in the terminal:

```
$ umask 
0002
```

The first `0` indicates the absence of [SUID/SGID/Sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), it is the default first bit value so if we don't need to set any of those three bits we usually don't use this bit.

The `umask` value is actually deducted from 777 (in case of a directory) and from 666 (In case of a file) to get the permission of a newly created file/directory. So, if the `umask` is `0002` the newly created file by this user will have a permission of `(666 - 002)=664` and a directory will have `(777 - 002)=775`.

To change the umask value for only current user permanently, put the `umask` value at the end of the `~/.bashrc` of the user. For example:

```
echo "umask 022" >> ~/.bashrc
```

For changing temporarily, run:

```
$ umask 022
```

The global `umask` value can be found and changed from `/etc/login.defs`:

```
$ grep "^UMASK" /etc/login.defs 
UMASK       022
```

****Note than you should not use `chmod`/`chown` randomly unless you are absolutely sure about the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

umask is correct but only covers the chmod part of your question, there is a more elegant way to do this.

To make sure, that you don't have to chown or chmod again, put your user to the www-data group of the apache webserver, like so:

```
useradd -G my-user www-data
```

With this add you are able to wirte in this folder and the username and group will be exactly what you asked for. Also with this, you don't even need to chmod again, because the webserver can read it, and so the content can be delivered without any restrictions.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group-www-data/